# Visualize values for polar coordinates in a circular heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, polar-coordinates

I have a 2D array, where every cell marks a range of an angle and a radius, e.g. `array[0][0]` marks the area between an angle of -180 degrees and -178.5 degrees and a radius between 0 and 2. In the cell, there is a value I want to visualize in a circular heatmap, where the areas for the given angle and radius range are colored depending on the value.

Similar to this:
[image]

Any way to do this?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/index.html ?

Comment: Not quite, see my edit

Comment: You could leverage the `polar_bar_demo.py` of that link to achieve what you want. Plot the cells with largest `r`, first, then the cells with successively lower `r` on top (`alpha` has to be zero).

Comment: I thinks you should do your own script based on the polar plot of matplotlib and take inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382459/half-or-quarter-polar-plots-in-matplotlib, and adapt it...